# Spotfire- calculated column with row ratios based on condition

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I’m having trouble understanding if Spotfire allows for conditional computations between arbitrary rows containing numerical data repeated over data groups. I could not find anything to cue me onto a right solution.

Context (simplified): I have data from a sensor reporting state of a process and this data is grouped into bursts/groups representing a measurement  taking several minutes each. 
Within each burst the sensor is measuring a signal and if a predefined feature (signal shape) was detected the sensor outputs some calculated value, V quantifying this feature and also reports a RunTime at which this happened.

So in essence I have three columns: Burst number, a set of RTs within this burst and Values associated with these RTs.
I need to add a calculated column  to do a ratio of Values for rows where RT is equal to a specific number, let’s say 1.89 and 2.76.

[image: example of data table]

The high level logic would be:

If a Value exists at 1.89 Run Time and a Value exists at 2.76 Run Time then compute the ratio of these values. Repeat for every Burst.
I understand I can repeat the computation over groups using OVER operator but I’m struggling with logic within each group...
Any tips would be appreciated.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do here is apply an order to your dataset. I assume the sample data is complete and encompasses the cases in your real data, thus, we create a calculated column:

```
RowID() as [ROWID]
```

Once this is done, we can create a calculated column which will compute your ratio over it's respective groups. Just a note, your `B4` example is incorrect compared to the other groups. That is, you have your numerator and denominator reversed.

```
If(([RT]=1.89) or ([RT]=2.76),[Value] / Max([Value]) OVER (Intersect([Burst],Previous([ROWID]))))
```

Breaking this down...

- `If(([RT]=1.89) or ([RT]=2.76),` limits the rows to those where the `RT = 1.89 or 2.76`.
- Next comes the evaluation if the above condition is `TRUE`
- `[Value] / Max([Value]) OVER (Intersect([Burst],Previous([ROWID]))))` This takes the value for the row and divides it by the `Max([Value])` over the grouping of `[Burst]` and `AllPrevious([ROWID])`. This is noted by the `Intersect()` function. So, the denominator will always be the *previous* value for the grouping. Note that `Max()` was a simple aggregate used, but any should do for this case since we are only expecting a single value. All `Over()` functions require and aggregate to limit the result set to a single row.

**RESULTS**

[image: Results]

Comment: Brilliant! Many thanks scsimon!
I’m quite new to Spotifre and I still struggle with node navigation in expressions. I knew that IF statements limit the data but did not quite realise a node is made within which you can navigate using methods like Previous and out of which you need to escape using Intersect. 
Many thanks again.

Comment: No worries at all mate